# golang simple static server print on terminal

Tags: go

this is my initial golang code :

```
package main
import (
    "net/http"
    "io"
)

const hello = `hello world`


func helloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, hello)
}


func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", helloHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":1088", nil)
}
```

it is a simple http server, i need add new function, every get request print in linux terminal ip, METHOD, /request.

example output in terminal need:

```
95.250.33.36 GET /
95.250.33.36 GET /favicon.ico
95.250.33.36 GET /robots.txt
```

how i can do this ?

Comment: `fmt.Println`?.

Comment: this is my first day developing in golang, i dont know how call ip and request

Comment: `r *http.Request` <-- you have it already here. Check the type structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing about Golang is interfaces.
Your `helloHandler` actually implements the [`HandlerFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) interface.
Using the [Open/Close Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) we can take `helloHandler` and extend it for logging the request in the following way:

```
func wrapHandlerWithLogging(wrappedHandler http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
       log.Printf("--> %s %s", req.Method, req.URL.Path)
       wrappedHandler.ServeHTTP(w, req)
    })
}

func main() {
    ...
    http.HandleFunc("/", wrapHandlerWithLogging(http.HandlerFunc(helloHandler)))
    ...
 }
```

So basically, we wrap `helloHandler` which implements `HandlerFunc` with another `HandlerFunc`.

In this example, we only log the request method (GET, POST, PUT and etc) and the request path (e.g. '/'). However, you can log other data:

- `req.RemoteAddr` network address that sent the request
- `req.Proto` the protocol version
- `req.Host` specifies the host on which URL is sought

Comment: what is wrong ? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/65ba98783c4e4d00ac6c1326853220c3

Comment: root@kali:~/ss# go run 111.go 
# command-line-arguments
./111.go:14: undefined: wrapperHandler in wrapperHandler.ServeHTTP
./111.go:27: cannot use helloHandler (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) as type http.Handler in argument to wrapHandlerWithLogging:
 func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)
./111.go:27: cannot use wrapHandlerWithLogging(helloHandler) (type http.Handler) as type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) in argument to http.HandleFunc

Comment: @kingcope I fixed the code. Please feel free to test.

Comment: @kingcope why haven't you checked the `http.Request` as I suggested 40 minutes ago? How are you supposed to learn, if you don't even bother reading the documentation?